# Revert to Old Google Apps Mail Design

Tags: email, google-workspace

I clicked the button in my company's Google apps for the new design (the one that looks like Google+). I have tried it for several days thinking I just had to get used to it -- but that isn't the case. I just don't like it.

Can I revert back to the old version?

Answer (score 1):

I found it after some more looking. If you click the Cog Wheel or Gear icon, there is a revert to the old look option. **It was a little confusing because there are two gear icons**, you need the lower of the two:

[image]

I also noticed that there is compact version you can select for the new version which I think I will be okay with.

Answer (score 1):

If you click the cog in the top right you can switch back.

[image: Google Apps - Switch design]

However, this is only temporary and you will be forced to use the new version eventually.

Also, check out some of the other themes (`Mail Settings` > `Themes`) that are available. You might find them a bit easier on the eye.

Comment: I don't even have the revert option

Comment: @Barry It was a temporary thing so probably won't be there now.